# Display PHP without it being rendered

Tags: php

In a PHP page, how can I write PHP documentation without it being rendered?

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
<?php _e( 'Error msg, please manually add <?php echo "whatever"; ?> to this
file, 'my-text-domain' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities to display them literally, just like you would in ordinary HTML:

```
<?php _e( 'Error msg, please manually add &lt;?php echo "whatever"; ?&gt; to this file, 'my-text-domain' ); ?>
```

You could also call the `htmlentities()` function to do it automatically:

```
<?php _e( htmlentities('Error msg, please manually add <?php echo "whatever"; ?> to this file, 'my-text-domain') ); ?>
```